# Using sigma notation to find the function

Tags: calculus, integration

Question: Find a function $f$ on $[3,8]$ such that the 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1+\log{(3+5k/n)}} e^{-3-(5k/n)}\frac{5}{n} $$
is equal to
$$\int_3^8 f(x) \, dx$$

Having a lot of trouble with this question. Does this involve u substitution in some way?

Comment: I've made a guess at formatting what you meant in MathJax. Please edit it if this is not what you mean.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That was the right question. Need to learn how to do that

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1):

This is a Riemann sum for
$$ f(x) = e^{-x}\sqrt{1+\log{x}}: $$
such a sum looks like
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n h f(a+kh), $$
where $h$ is the width of the rectangles, and $f$ is sampled at the points at the upper-right of each rectangle, $a+kh$. This sum uses $n$ rectangles of width $h=5/n$, and the sample points are at $3+kh=3+5k/n$.

(Of course, actually doing this integral looks pretty grim, but thankfully you didn't ask that!)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$f(x)=\sqrt{1+\log(x)}e^{-x}$$ and use Riemann sums.